# How can I read an value or deserialize this JSON-structure in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json

from an associative and multidimensional Array in PHP i get this object by json_encode():

```
{"2047":
  {"f1a":
   {"val":["7","7","6","1","6","6"],
    "cnt":6,
    "sum":33,
    "avg":5.5
   },
  {"f2a":
   {"val":["7","6","5","7","5","3","5","7","6","7"],
    "cnt":10,
    "sum":58,
    "avg":5.8
   },
  "2048": ...
}
```

and i want to read the value of avg of f2a and 2047.

Comment: No @David OP wants to read in Javascript.  Use `JSON.parse` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: That is not valid JSON. `2047` should be an array.

Comment: Are you trying to read it in PHP or JavaScript?

In JavaScript, you can always get the object from the string using `JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: The problem is the number. And I want to read it in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var myJson = {
  2047: {
    f1a: {
      val: [7, 7, 6, 1, 6, 6],
      cnt: 6,
      sum: 33,
      avg: 5.5
    },
      f2a: {
        val: [7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 7],
        cnt: 10,
        sum: 58,
        avg: 5.8
      }
  }
};
console.log(myJson['2047']['f1a']['avg']);
```

Comment: `myJson` is not a JSON

Comment: copy paste and see

Comment: its not about if its working or not, its just not the solution for the TP - you just log properties of an usual object. this has nothing to do with `json`

Comment: is it the variable name that hurts you ? just read the main question

Comment: bro it is the topic that "hurts" me - `How can I read an value or deserialize this JSON-structure in Javascript?` - your example does not handle any JSONs so what are we talking about. Learn about json here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: The code it doesn't work without breaks. if I make breaks it works fine. Why?

Comment: both of you should get familiar with the definition of a `json`...  w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp ; i do not want to struggle with you. This is just what it is

Comment: Thank you, guigoz. In this  way I can read all. Only with parseJson doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize your JSON with `JSON.parse (serialized)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var obj = JSON.parse(str)`, then traverse the object using `obj['2047']['f1a']`